# Why HTTP GET with Request body in swagger & node js NOT working?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm trying to Send a GET request to my api to obtain some result. i'm using `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I successfully get the result using the following curl:

```
curl -k -X GET https://localhost:8443/parser -H 'accept: */*' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "mydata=1"
```

the '-k' is because I'm using https.

However, when I'm using the following swagger in Nodejs

```
 * @swagger
 * /parser:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Get scenario validation result.
 *     requestBody:
 *       content:
 *         application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               mydata:
 *                 type: string
 *
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: success
 */
```

it returns an error TypeError: `Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.`

and the curl appeard as the follwoing :

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost:8443/parser' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'mydata=8.1'
```

any hint?

Answer (score 0):

[GET is not supposed to have a request body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625554/113116), and OpenAPI 3.0 Specification explicitly does not allow `requestBody` in GET, HEAD, and DELETE requests. (This restriction was later lifted in OAS 3.1 though.) When using GET, you can send data in the URL query string (`http(s)://...?key1=value1&key2=value2&...`) or request headers instead.

If you *must* use a request body (e.g. if the payload is huge or has a complex structure), use POST, PUT, or PATCH instead, depending on the request semantics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sending in a Get Request a 4 kb text which is a language syntax to validate the lang and return the result so there is no need for post. My API is only configured with GET requests. What do you think should i do ?

Comment: Sounds like a typical use case for POST to me. Change your API to use POST instead of GET. Problem solved.